# Python & Pandas - Using chr(255) as a separator

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to parse firewall logs with Python & Pandas but i'm having issues with getting the correct separator to work;

In my current log data :

```
num�date�time�orig�type�action�alert�i/f_name�i/f_dir�product�log_sys_message�origin_id�ProductFamily�src�dst�proto�message_info�service�s_port�rule�rule_uid�rule_name�service_id�xlatesrc�xlatedst�NAT_rulenum�NAT_addtnl_rulenum�xlatedport�xlatesport�ICMP�ICMP Type�ICMP Code�rule_guid�hit�policy�first_hit_time�last_hit_time�log_id�description�status�version�comment�update_service�TCP packet out of state�tcp_flags�sys_message:�inzone�outzone�Protection Name�Severity�Confidence Level�protection_id�SmartDefense Profile�Performance Impact�Industry Reference�Protection Type�Update Version�Attack Info�attack�capture_uuid�FollowUp�Total logs�Suppressed logs
0�24Oct2017�23:59:00�10.100.255.190�control� ��daemon�inbound�VPN-1 & FireWall-1�Log file has been switched to: 2017-10-24_235900.log�cteafmfw1�Network��������������������������������������������������
```

and the code:

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv('2017-10-25_235900.log-export.csv', sep='\xff', 
header=0, index_col=False)

print(file)
```

when i run this i can see that the separator is not processed; I've tried also assignin it to variable with value chr(255) as was proposed for similiar issue but cannot seem to get this separator prosessed at all.

I know that i can process the file and replace separator but as there is tons of data with this separator already would be nice to know is it even possible to get this working?

Comment: Are you sure that's the separator? I can't see what it is in your question. Try opening it in a latin-1 encoding.

Comment: it should be hex FF, and if doing: echo -e '\xff' i get the same character as well if i print '\xff' in python, so i have at least assumed that it is the character.

Comment: Did you try passing `encoding='latin-1'` to `read_csv`?

Comment: Adding: encoding='latin-1' to read_csv params solved this - thank you!

Comment: Great. You could either post an answer, or I could post an answer which you'd accept, or you could delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other wondering the same:

Adding "encoding='latin-1'" to read_csv params solved this

Thanks @ COLDSPEED